# quotient norms in a Banach algebra

Tags: ideals, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a Banach algebra and $I, J$ be two sided closed ideals of it. Let $I\subseteq J$, can we see $\|a+J\|\leq \|a+I\|$, for every $a\in A$, in general?
and when it is an equality?

Comment: These are different norms by the way. The inequality does hold (by definition).

Comment: Given a closed idea $J$ we define the norm on $A/J$ to be $\|a+J\| = \inf_{j\in J} \|a+j\|$ so clearly the inequality holds. Equality never holds for every $a\in A$ unless $I=J$.